# Computing derivative of parametric equation

Tags: derivatives, parametric

This is probably a silly question but I am just not sure if I understand what to do.

So I have the parametric equations:

$x=6\cos (t)-2\\   y=5\sin (t)+3$

I am asked to compute $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ at the point $(3\sqrt{2}-2, 3-\frac{5}{\sqrt{2}})$

So 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}\implies\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{5\cos(t)}{6\sin(t)}$$

Now where do I plug the above numbers in to find $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$? Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $\cos t = \dfrac{x+2}{6}$, and $\sin t = \dfrac{y-3}{5}$

Comment: Ah ha! Thank you very much! I will accept your answer as soon as it lets me!